# How can I delete child rows from child tables in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

I have several child tables that reference a parent table. I need to delete rows from such child tables only. I'm not looking for delete on cascade. How can I achieve this? Or is this impossible because of the foreign key?

Thanks

Comment: There is no problem when you delete *child* rows.

Comment: @forpas hi! yes, you are right! Sorry I may have misunderstood some things but are clear now. I'm a bit distracted sometimes!